# How to use Fiddler with Windows Defender Application Guard on Edge browser

Tags: windows-10, security, microsoft-edge, windows-defender, fiddler

I'm on latest Windows 10 Enterprise edition (personal PC).

I have latest Fiddler and Edge browser installed (stable and canary channels).

Fiddler's root certificate is installed and trusted, it can detect and decrypt all HTTPS connections in my computer from all apps, but Windows Defender Application Guard window in Edge fails to connect to the Internet.

[image]
[image]
[image]

how can I fix this so that I can monitor traffic inside WDAG container with Fiddler?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler cannot work with Application Guard because of a small incompatibility.

The Microsoft FAQ about Application Guard has this section:

> [**How do I configure Microsoft Defender Application Guard to work
> with my network proxy (IP-Literal
> Addresses)?**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-application-guard/faq-md-app-guard#how-do-i-configure-microsoft-defender-application-guard-to-work-with-my-network-proxy-ip-literal-addresses)
>
> **Microsoft Defender Application Guard requires proxies to have a
> symbolic name**, not just an IP address. IP-Literal proxy settings such
> as `192.168.1.4:81` can be annotated as `itproxy:81` or using a record
> such as `P19216810010` for a proxy with an IP address of
> `192.168.100.10`. This applies to Windows 10 Enterprise edition 1709
> or higher. These would be for the proxy policies under Network
> Isolation in Group Policy or Intune.

If you start Fiddler and go to *Settings > Network & Internet > Proxy*,
you will see under "Manual proxy setup" that:

- The setting "Use a proxy server" has turned itself to On
- Address has become `http=127.0.0.1:8888;https=127.0.0.1:8888`

The problem here is that Application Guard does not accept such a URL,
as it requires the proxy to be identified by name and not by IP address.

If you now try to change that URL to `https=localhost:8888` so as to give it
a name, and then click the Save button, Fiddler will immediately turn
Capture to Off, and will put up a large notice in yellow saying:
"The system proxy was changed. Click to reenable capturing".
And if you click the yellow header ... the proxy's URL in Settings
returns to `http=127.0.0.1:8888;https=127.0.0.1:8888` (!).

As far as I can see, the situation is unsolvable: The two applications are
mutually incompatible. This might perhaps be by design.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
would you recommend another similar software like Fiddler that can be used to monitor WDAG connections properly? maybe Charles proxy or the new Fiddler?

Comment: I did my tests on the new Fiddler. The problem is that all such products which set  the proxy to `127.0.0.1` will fail in exactly the same way. You could try to find a debugger that can be configured to use a named proxy, but I can't help you there.

Comment: Thank you. my goal is to detect traffic in WDAG using its header.
Microsoft Edge recently added this new feature to canary under a flag called
 `Application Guard Traffic Idenfication`
`- If enabled, Application Guard traffic will be tagged with a X-MS-ApplicationGuard-Initiated header -`

so I was wondering how is it even possible for someone to do it if these popular tools are failing like this. fiddler would let me easily flag all the traffic containing that header.
there is also `pac` file but when i use it in Fiddler, no traffic goes through it. it's like WDAG bypasses pac file.

Comment: One method would be to use another computer or VM to act as a debugging gateway, because then it would have a name.

Comment: If you only want to monitor WDAG traffic then you can try PolarProxy. It will generate a pcap file with **decrypted** traffic. You will have to make sure the WDAG traffic is routed to PolarProxy somehow though, since it is a transparent proxy. The easiest solution would be to add a static entry for the intercepted domain into your `hosts` file, pointing to PP's IP. 

Disclaimer: I am a PP developer

Comment: @Erik Hi, i went to your website but i can't find PolarProxy binaries to download, where is the .exe file?
https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy

Comment: @Sam The is unfortunately not yet any Windows build of PolarProxy. You will need to run it on a Linux machine. We do have plans to release a Windows build in the future though.

Comment: @Sam PolarProxy is now available as a Windows x64 download

Answer (score 1):

It's because underlying it's a VM so couldn't use host's loopback network.

I didn't use fiddle but I did get my VM connect to internet through a proxy

Here's my solution:

1. install docker desktop. docker provides a special hostname "host.docker.internal" that points to host machine. Any VM including windows defender application guard can take advantage of this.
2. on host set your system proxy to host.docker.internal:port and you're good to go.